# Mapping keystrokes to images in C#

Tags: c#, keyboard, mapping, keystroke

I was hoping to get some guidance on a project that I'm not even sure can work. I want to write an application in C# that allows me to type with my keyboard, but what shows up on the screen is a specific image from an image bank. So, I'll have a few images stored, and I'd like to map each keystroke from my keyboard to a stored image. Is something like this possible?

If not, is it possible to write some sort of library that I can import into MS Word, which would do something similar for me?

Comment: Do you mean you want to create a font where each character is a small image?  Microsoft have a font creation SDK https://www.microsoft.com/typography/DevToolsOverview.mspx, and there are other tools available. But this wouldn't be something you do in C#.

Comment: That is kind of what I was thinking, but I thought this type of approach would involve a lot more overhead than this project needs. Is it actually very complicated, or is my thinking incorrect?

Also, what language would this approach be using?

Comment: Creating a font isn't particularly complicated as far as I'm aware, I've never done it but there seem to be plenty of tutorials on the web. I'd imagine it's pretty time consuming however. Fonts are monochrome so not exactly like mapping keys to images, so if your requirement isn't exactly to create a font then it maybe worth clarifying the question a bit. Are you just saying you want a program to listen for key presses and popup an image in the middle of the screen?  If so that's pretty trivial but nothing at all like creating a font.

Comment: Are you saying you want pictures to appear wherever you can type (text boxes on webpages, command line windows, etc), or just in MS-Word?

Comment: Thanks for the help! I searched more online, and I found http://fontstruct.com which is really simple to use.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new font with http://fontstruct.com . It's pretty straight forward to use. Once you've made your font, you can download it as a true type font, and install it to your computer.

Thanks for the help!